# Intersection between parametric curves (Cylinder and plane)

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametrization

I have this question here.

> The parametric curve $\vec{r}_1(t)=4t\vec{i}+(2t-2)\vec{j}+(6t^2-7)\vec{k}$ is given.
>   Show the the curve is at the intersection between a plane and a cylinder.

If I let the plane be $x-2y=0$, then I get $4t-2(2t-2)=x-2y=2$ which is a plane so the parametric equation satisfies the equation of a plane.

What about the cylinder though? I'm very much stuck on how to set up $x^2+y^2=r^2$ to get the cylinder. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This curve is not the intersection of a plane and a (default, circular) cylinder.  It *is* the intersection of a plane and a parabolic cylinder.

Comment: Okay but in that case, I have $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. What would I set my $a$ and $b$ to? I can't get a 1 no matter what I try.

Comment: An ellipse (the equation you have written) is not a parabola.  The given curve is *not* the intersection of a plane and either a circular parabola or an elliptic parabola.  (Since the plane is not parallel to the axis of either cylinder, such a curve would have two points where $\mathrm{d}z/\mathrm{d}t = 0$, but this curve only has one.)

Comment: Okay. How would I set up the equation of the cylinder then? I'm having some trouble figuring that part out. What could I pick as my parametrization?

Comment: I note that the projection onto the $xz$-plane is a parabola, so a parabolic cylinder perpendicular to that plane would suffice.

Comment: Fine, I have no $y$ component then. How would I get an equation from that?

Comment: Have you considered eliminating $t$ between the $x$ and $z$ components, *exactly the same way you got your equation for your plane*?

Comment: I have yes but if I have the equation of a cylinder, I have to square both vectors so I have $(4t)^2=16t^2$ and $(6t^2-7)^2$ but that will be a quartic so that won't get rid of any $t$ values. So I tried to eliminate my $t$'s using $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't see the word "parabolic" that has been used repeatedly in the preceding?

Comment: I'm using the reference here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces.aspx (Roughly halfway)

Either I'll get a circular cylinder or a cylinder with elliptical cross sections.

Comment: I'll repeat myself:  The curve you have given is not the intersection of a plane and a circular cylinder.  The curve you have given is not the intersection of a plane and an elliptic cylinder.  EIther the axis of either cylinder lies parallel to the plane you have found, so the parametric curve is (one or) two parallel lines (which it is not) or the axis is not parallel to the plane, in which case the parametric curve is an ellipse (which it is not).  Continuing to ignore that this curve is not of the form you want achieves nothing.

Comment: Hi. No I get that but how can something like a parabolic cylinder possibly exist? Doesn't a cylinder have to be a closed surface? A parabola has no bounds so you'll have a cylinder which opens in a direction resembling a parabola but the endpoints will never be contained.

Comment: [parabolic cylinder](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinder.html) [as an example of a cylindrical surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry)#Cylindrical_surfaces)

Comment: That's quite the eye opener. So essentially, I translate a a curve parallel to one of the coordinate vectors and that's the definition of a cylinder.